# Write RTL String on a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel

I receive two Strings from a server

```
firstString = "JHKJ"
secondSctring = "ذيس إز اى تست"
```

On LTR mode, I want the label to print `JHKJ:  ذيس إز اى تست` and on RTL I expect it to print `ذيس إز اى تست : JHKJ`

If I normally concatenate the strings

```
let finalString = firstString  + ":" + secondSctring
```

The label shows the same result on both RTL and LTR:

```
JHKJ:  ذيس إز اى تست
```

And even if I change the concatenation order

```
if rtl{
finalString =  secondSctring + ":" + firstString
}else{
finalString = firstString  + ":" + secondSctring
}
```

myLabelView.text = finalString

the result still the same :

```
JHKJ:  ذيس إز اى تست
```

I also tried to force th label to use only LTR mode, it didn't helped. I also tried to use two attributed string and append them in a third one, it also didn't work. Do you have an idea on how to solve this without using two labels?

Comment: Could you send a snippet of your code ? Did you try with this syntax : `print("\(firstString):\(secondSctring)")` ?

Comment: I am not printing the text, I am adding it to a lableView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before some time I faced same issue and I managed to do it with

> The 0x200E unicode character is invisible but puts the rendering back into left-to-right mode.

After the above, this is the output that I'm getting:

```
let firstString = "JHKJ"
let secondSctring = "ذيس إز اى تست"

let finalString = firstString  + ":" + secondSctring

var result1: String = "\u{200E}\(secondSctring) : \(firstString)"
var result2: String = "\u{200E}\(firstString) : \(secondSctring)"
```

> ‎**result1** ذيس إز اى تست : JHKJ
>
> **result2** JHKJ : ذيس إز اى تست

Hope it is helpful to you